# (Confusing in evaluating the Integral) Derivation of Three-Step Adam-Bashforth

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Please check this site first (Optional, doesn't really help):

[Adam-Bashforth-Moulton](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Adams-Bashforth_and_Adams-Moulton_methods)

What i'm confused about is in the exercise part for finding the Adam-Bashforth :

> **So the integral of each part of $P(t)$ is** :
>
> $$\dfrac{f(t_n,
> y_n)}{2h^2}\int_{t_n}^{t_{n+1}}(t-t_{n-1})(t-t_{n-2})\,\Bbb
>  dt=\dfrac{23}{12}hf(t_n,y_n)$$

Where does $\dfrac{23}{12}$ come from?

The variable is little weird. That integration is integrated w.r.t variable $t$. But there are another variables like $t_n, t_{n-1}$, are those variables in this integration considered as *A Constant*?

What should i do? Expand the term, and then integrate it w.r.t $t$? But what about another $t_k$????

Please help me, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the time sequence $t_k=t_0+kh$ is considered constant. Then
$$
\int_{t_n}^{t_{n+1}}(t-t_{n-1})(t-t_{n-2})dt = \int_0^h(s+h)(s+2h)ds
=\left[\frac{s^3}3+\frac{3hs^2}2+2h^2s\right]_0^h\\
=\frac{h^3}6(2+9+12)=2h^2\cdot\frac{23h}{12}
$$

Comment: Dr. Lutz is my Helper! Thank you very much...

Comment: Hi Dr. I want to clarify this if my thought is true. Based on your work, if you make a change variable of that integral to $s$, then it must be $$s=t-t_n$$ and it must be $$t_{n+1}=t_n+h$$ isn't it? For example if we want to do change variable the bounds. $$1)\, t=t_n\to s=(t_n)-t_n=0$$ $$2)\, t=t_{n+1}\to s=t_{n+1}-t_n=h$$ for the integrand $$t-t_{n-1}=t-(t_n-h)=s+h$$ and $$t-t_{n-2}=t-(t_n-2h)=s+2h$$. The last one is change the $\Bbb dt$ that is $$t=s+t_n \iff \Bbb dt= \Bbb ds$$

Comment: Yes, all you write is true and leads to the substitution. One could also have used $t=t_n+sh$, $s\in [0,1]$ to get a more "standard" or "normalized" integration.

Comment: I'm sorry, i've edited it. Please reload the page.